# unused functions detection utility for c

Tags: c, code-analysis

I am trying to measure my code coverage utilization on a C project consist of several libraries, and main program.

Is there a utility that can help me find which function I dont use from both libraries and main program.

I want to build list of functions (public functions) that are not used by my main program, in order to ignore them in my code coverage report.

Comment: FYI, many compilers (e.g. GCC) can warn you about unused `static` (i.e. private) functions.

Comment: Why don't you get a code coverage tool?

Comment: The code coverage tool tells me which functions I called, It doesn't tell which functions are unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cflow can create a call graph for the program, but it doesn't work well with pointers to functions in some cases.

for eaxample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int f1(){
        return 1;
}

int (*p_f1)() = f1;

int main() {
        p_f1();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using gcc you compile your code with [option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

```
-Wunused-function
```

> Warn whenever a static function is declared but not defined or a non-inline static function is unused. This warning is enabled by -Wall.

Comment: I also want to know which public function I dont use in the project. -Wunused-function doesn't warn me about such

Comment: nm will tell you both which ones do get referenced (run it on the .o's) and which ones exist (run it on the executable and any .so's).

Comment: nm will not give me names of the used "private functions" from the library

Comment: that's why you also run it on the .o's that go into them

Answer (score 0):

There are coverage tools available for free - for example "gcov" that runs on go with the gcc tool suite. However, Code Coverage only tells you which functions get hit by your testing (or whatever you do to excercise the code), so for example

```
ptr = malloc(...);
if (!ptr)
{
   allocation_failed(__FILE__, __LINE__);
}
```

would only show that allocation_failed is called if you are also using some tool that makes your allocations fail from time to time.

I'm not aware of a tool that will show you what functions are not used across larger systems (with multiple libraries, etc). I expect you could make something by using the output of "nm" and a bit of "pulling things in". It won't cover foo and bar as unusued in this case:

```
unit1.c:
   extern int foo(void);

   int bar()
   {
       return foo();
   }


unit2.c:

   int foo(void)
   {
      return 42;
   }

   int baz(void)
   {
      return bar();
   }
```

and then baz isn't used anywhere. But if you remove baz, it will show that bar is not called, and then you can remove foo after that...

Edit: Crazy idea time - how about taking every C file in the project and just concatenating the whole thing into a a single .C file, then add static at the beginning of every function, and compiling with -Wunused-functon - I'm sure there will be some "interesting" effects from this if your code isn't extremely well written, but it may be worth a try [it would be fairly easy to do this in a Linux system, something like `find . -name "*.c" -print | xargs cat {} > giantsource.c` - you then need a little bit of sed or something to label all functions static, which I'm not quite sure how you'd go about doing - it depends very much on the formatting of your code.

You may want to have a look at this: 
http://www.gedanken.demon.co.uk/cxref/

I haven't used it, but any decent cross referencing tool should be able to identify anything that is "not used" as not having any references. Of course, you'll probably still have to run over the code severa times to weed out the functions that are used by functions that aren't being called, etc.

Comment: I did say that it was probably a crazy idea... ;)

Comment: Added a link to a cross referencing tool. Don't know if it's any good.

Answer (score 0):

`cflow` has an option to build a cross-reference table: `--xref`

The format of the output is described by [GNU cflow: Cross-Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Cross_002dReferences.html)

GNU cflow is also able to produce cross-reference listings. This mode is enabled by `--xref` (`-x`) command line option. Cross-reference output lists each symbol occurrence on a separate line. Each line shows the identifier and the source location where it appears. If this location is where the symbol is defined, it is additionally marked with an asterisk and followed by the definition. For example, here is a fragment of a cross-reference output for d.c program:

```
printdir * d.c:42 void printdir (int level,char *name)
printdir   d.c:74
printdir   d.c:102
```

It shows that the function printdir is defined in line 42 and referenced twice, in lines 74 and 102.

To detect unused functions, search the line with a star not followed by a line with the same prefix. The following GNU Awk code print the unused functions:

```
 {
   if( $2 == "*" ) {
      if( f ) {
         print f
      }
      f = $1
   }
   else {
      f = ""
   }
}
```

The command may be:

```sh
cflow -x src/*.c src-gen/*.c | awk -f find-unused-functions.awk
```